# PyQt: QFileDialog close directly after opening

Tags: qt, pyqt, cross-platform, ipython, qfiledialog

I am using `QFileDialog` (both `getOpenFileName` and `getSaveFileName`) but have a strange behavior:

- if I call them directly from a (ipython) shell, I have no problem
- if I call them from a widget:

  - in mac 10.6, it closes the dialog just after opening it (the dialog "pop" then close)
  - in mac 10.6, it works fine if I use the `QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog`
  - in win xp (in a virtualbox) it works without the `DontUseNativeDialog` option
  - in win xp, with the `DontUseNativeDialog` option, the dialog close right after opening
  - in win 7, both seems to work (someone else did the test, so I did not see it my-self)

My questions:

- what would be the reasons for the dialog to close right after opening, in general?
- why would it do that in some cases but not all?
- how should I do to make it work cross-platform?

Comment: Could you post a minimilistic working example that demonstrates the behaviour, just so we can rule out common Qt mistakes (eg objects being garbage collected because you aren't holding onto a reference to an object, or similar)

Comment: Trying to make a minimalist example, I found out that it comes from a  strange conflict with ipython and its `--pylab` start option. The problem can be avoided by either executing the code directly (`python xxxx.py`), or by not using the pylab option. In both cases the qapplication should be started manually.

Comment: I am not sure if I should remove the question or edit it and give the answer above. Explanation on why there is a conflict could still be interesting.

Comment: I have no concrete knowledge of why there is a conflict, but I guess pylab's use of Qt is messing with things. It's worth leaving the question up anyway in case someone else has the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this problem comes from a strange conflict with ipython and its `--pylab` start option. It can thus be avoided by either

- executing the code directly using `python xxxx.py`
- or by not using the pylab option

In both cases, the qapplication should be started manually:

```
qapp = QtGui.QApplication([])
my_app = MyQtAppWindow(...)
my_app.exec_()
```

However, I still don't know why there is a conflict.